# Cloud Build fails to deploy Cloud Run after started using Google Cloud Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have been using Google Cloud with free trial account.

I was able to deploy Cloud Run builds from my Github repository. However, since I have started using a Google Cloud Kubernetes Cluster & Jobs using 2 VM in Google Compute Engine, the Cloud Run deployments have started failing :

```
Step #2 - "Deploy": gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
Step #2 - "Deploy": Deploying...
Step #2 - "Deploy": failed
Step #2 - "Deploy": Deployment failed
Step #2 - "Deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 30.
Step #2 - "Deploy": Consider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account.
Finished Step #2 - "Deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

[image]

How much CPU is required for succesful Cloud Run deployments ? Here is the Inline Cloud Run deployment yaml file :

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack
    env:
      - GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT=$_ENTRYPOINT
    args:
      - build
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1'
      - '--network=cloudbuild'
      - '--path=.'
      - '--env=GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT'
    id: Buildpack
    entrypoint: pack
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID,$_LABELS
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
substitutions:
  _LABELS: gcb-trigger-id=xxxxxx-d5fd-47b7-8949-xxxxxxxxxx
  _TRIGGER_ID: xxxxxx-d5fd-47b7-8949-xxxxxxxxxx
  _DEPLOY_REGION: europe-west1
  _GCR_HOSTNAME: eu.gcr.io
  _PLATFORM: managed
  _SERVICE_NAME: videoo-app-dev
  _ENTRYPOINT: 'gunicorn -b :$PORT videoo.wsgi'
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed
  - videoo-app-devs
```

What should be the approach here to recover backs successful deployments ?

Comment: What is your CPU quota for that region? It looks like you need to either use a different region or request a quota increase. https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Comment: How do I check my cpu quota for that region?

Comment: Did you read the document link I provided? "Check your quota" is the second item in the index at the top of the page.

Comment: Ok, I have checked it, but my question is : how much CPU or resources does Cloud Build or Cloud Run implicitly requires for deploying the Cloud Run Application ?

Comment: Also what I cannot understand from this error : Is this a Cloud Build or Cloud Run error ?

Comment: The error is coming from Cloud Run. Cloud Build is running the command. You have a quota problem, the solution is to increase the quota. You might be able to switch regions, but since you are on a Free Trial account, you probably must contact Google. Think of quotas as credit limits. You hit yours.

Comment: As mentioned by John Hanley, this is a quota issue.  The CPU will depend on what you are trying to deploy and how much CPU you are going to be using. You can use the following `Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Quotas > Increase Requests` to request a quota increase or use the following [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.252973260.457939111.1659926696-256663623.1650917346) to come up with a quota that will allow you to run the application with the free trial.

Comment: Here is another link that you can use to determine how far can you go with the [free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add in your args

```
--max-instances=29
```

or any amount less than 30

Answer (score 5):

Just go to the cloud run page : Click on Edit and Deploy New Version.
Now just decrease the autoscaling to 30 or 50, the maximum number of instances allowed will be mentioned on the error.

I had the same issue yesterday.